# How do I filter title and alt attributes in the gallery shortcode?

Tags: filters, gallery

I am displaying a post gallery inside a custom post type, using the following in my single-custom.php template:

`<?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery id="'.$post->ID.'" link="file" columns="5" orderby="menu_order"]'); ?>`

One of the things included in the output is `title="filename"` in the `<img>` tag, like so:

`<img width="150" height="150" src="http://mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/DSC_0036-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="DSC_0036" title="DSC_0036" />`

I do not want to output the title attribute. Mostly, I don't want crappy filenames in the hover-over text, but there are hundreds of images and I'm not prepared to go into the Media Gallery and edit the title for each one. I'd prefer to also change the `alt` attribute to the post name, perhaps.

Is there a way to filter the gallery to output the post name in the alt and title attributes, instead of the filename?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `[gallery]` shortcode is parsed by [`gallery_shortcode()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.5/wp-includes/media.php#L743), which calls [`wp_get_attachment_link()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.5/wp-includes/media.php#L587), which in turns calls [`wp_get_attachment_image()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.5/wp-includes/media.php#L617). This latter function writes the `<img>` tag with the `title` attribute. You're lucky, because the attributes are filtered through `wp_get_attachment_image_attributes`, so you can hook into that and remove the `title`.

To do this, you attach the hook before you call the shortcode and remove it after you did this. You can either do this in your template if it's a one-off, or, if you are more advanced, you "hijack" the `[gallery]` shortcode with your own function that adds the hook, calls the original `gallery_shortcode()` function, and removes the hook.

Comment: I tried using this in my functions.php: `function replace_image_tag($html, $title){   
      $html = str_replace('title=""','title="Post"',$html);
        return $html;
     }
     add_filter('get_image_tag','replace_image_tag');` but it didn't change the output of the gallery at all?

Comment: @Amanda: Where is `get_image_tag()` involved? You should filter `wp_get_attachment_image_attributes`, and remove the `title` element from the passed array.

Comment: I was looking at http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.5/wp-includes/media.php Thanks for the help, This works: `function ergosport_gallery_filter( $attr ) {
 $attr['alt'] = "Ergosport Models";
 $attr['title'] = "Click for a larger image";
 return $attr;
 }

add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'ergosport_gallery_filter' );`

Answer (score 0):

This is very useful, thanks to the both of you.
You can also add a copyright title attribute with the year automatically set:

`$attr['title'] = '© ' . date("Y") . ' Copyright ' . get_option('blogname');`

Comment: You should be encoding the copyright symbol.